How does crossing symmetry affect the value of an electroweak vertex (e.g. $u+W^-\to d$ vs. $W^-\to\pi^-$)?
Two of the weak charged current vertices I often encounter in my first foray into particle physics are $u+W^-\to d$ and $W^-\to\pi^-$, shown in the following Feynman diagrams:

These feel like the same process -- indeed, they are related by crossing $u$ over to $\overline{u}$ on the other side of the reaction. The two diagrams are topologically equivalent, except one has the label $u$ and the other has the label $\overline{u}$.
This makes me think that applying the Feynman rules would yield different results, since an incoming fermion gets a factor of $u_{s_i}(\mathbf{p_i})$, but an outgoing antifermion gets a factor of $v_{s_i'}(\mathbf{p_i'})$.
I think the bulk of my confusion comes from the relabeling of $u$ as $\overline{u}$ between the two diagrams. All the lists of allowed SM vertices that I've seen (e.g. this one on Wikipedia) only include the first version of the vertex, with no antiquarks. This (and the crossing symmetry between the two diagrams, and the fact that they are almost topologically equivalent) makes me feel that the two vertices posed in this question must be somehow equivalent.
What is the difference between these two vertices? More generally, when can I turn a particle into its antiparticle in a Feynman diagram?

All the time. The two diagrams correspond to the same term in the Lagrangian. Read your QFT text.

@CosmasZachos Thanks for the response. I understand they arise from the same term in the Lagrangian. Do they contribute equally to the amplitude when applying Feynman's rules?

Yes, but these are different amps, with different phase space. The first is unphysical.
